# "That certainly hasn't stopped you before"

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

A: Do you really think I slept with her? I have a girlfriend.

B: That certainly hasn't stopped you before.

Is B's response completely natural to use in this context? And is it phrased in a natural way? Is using "certainly" formal?

Comment: It sounds fine. Is there a reason you think "certainly" is formal, or do you have some alternative in mind you're wondering about?

Comment: using "certainly" isn't necessarily formal. In informal contexts, it brings emphasis on whatever action is "certain"

Answer (score 2):

B's response is natural sounding. I wouldn't say it's more formal in this context. Adding "certainly" might be a little "sassy" in terms of being "[distinctively smart and stylish](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sassy)". It helps convey a certain disbelief and annoyance B has toward A.

Comment: I agree. B's response is very natural sounding, and the use of "certainly" in this context isn't too formal. It would sound more formal if written this way: "Certainly, that hasn't stopped you before."